# Redirect cronjob to other page in PHP

Tags: php, cron

Im struggling with a PHP script that is activated by a cronjob every minute. It needs to redirect the cronjob to another page wat triggers something else, but i cant get it to work.

In that PHP file there is an if else function where it checks something in the database. When it is the 'if', the cronjob needs to be redirected to another page where it triggers something else external.

A header doesnt work, the cronjob doesnt listened to that. I also tried the file_get_contents($url) method, but this also just doesnt work.

How can i realise this?

Comment: Redirection doesn't work in a cronjob. Just include the logic which needs to be triggered in your if statement

Comment: @Daan cant do that. The logic is on another website, need to trigger that page to load it with certain login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `context` argument of `file_get_contents`:

```php
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'follow_location' => true
        )
    )
);

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```